# similar matrices in analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two matrices or bounded operators such that $A=\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n$ and $B=\lim_{n\to\infty} B_n$ for a sequence of matrices or operators $A_n$ and $B_n$. (The limit is to be understood as the matrix or operator norm.) Suppose in addition that for each $n$, $A_n$ is similar (i.e. conjugate) to $B_n$.

Does it follow that $A$ is similar to $B$? I think the answer is positive at least in some cases, for instance when $A_n$ and $B_n$ are matrices and are orthogonally similar.

I wonder what general statements can be proved (even by modifying the conditions, modes of convergence, etc) for this setting and in what cases counterexamples can be constructed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the limit of matrices just the pointwise limit? ie: lim{a_i,j}={lim a_i,j } ?

Comment: @Alephnull That's correct. (In finite-dimensions all norms are equivalent, so it really doesn't matter.)

Comment: Have you tried using the limit of the similarity matrices S_n ? Is there necessarily such a limit?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.  As a counterexample, consider sequences defined by
$$
A_n = A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}\\
B_n = \pmatrix{0&1/n\\0&0}, \quad B = 0
$$
Although each $A_n$ is similar to each $B_n$, the limit $A$ is not similar to the limit $B$.

---

Another counterexample:
$$
A_n = \pmatrix{1/n & 1\\0&0}, \quad B_n = \pmatrix{1/n & 0\\0&0}
$$

---

For orthogonal similarity: indeed, it is true (for matrices) that if each $A_n$ is orthogonal to each $B_n$, then the limits $A$ and $B$ are also orthogonally similar.  To show this, it suffices to apply the following fact:

> **Theorem:** Two matrices $P$ and $Q$ are orthogonally similar iff for every word $w$ on two generators, we have
>   $$
> \operatorname{trace}(w(P,P^*)) = \operatorname{trace}(w(Q,Q^*))
> $$

Now, it suffices to note that for any such $w$, we have 
$$
\operatorname{trace}(w(A_n,A_n^*)) \to \operatorname{trace}(w(A,A^*))
$$
which means that since each $A_n$ is orthogonally similar to the corresponding $B_n$, $A$ must be orthogonally similar to $B$.

Comment: I can't remember with certainty where I encountered that theorem, but I think it's in Horn and Johnson somewhere.

Comment: My gut feeling is that there is another argument that can be applied here which uses the compactness of the set of orthogonal matrices (which in turn spells bad news for the infinite dimensional case).

Comment: I have seen an argument which uses compactness as well, I believe, as well as some nice group theoretic properties.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Cool.  Let me know if you remember that reference.

Comment: This is a beautiful theorem; thanks for including it here. However, I think using it for the case of orthogonal similarity is overkill. An easier solution that I had thought of is based on the compactness of the set of orthogonal matrices to extract a convergent subsequence of the similarity matrices... . I wonder if anything interesting can be said in infinite dimensions. (As far as I can see, the theorem you've mentioned has no obvious infinite dimensional analogue.)

Comment: What you've said seems to be what I was saying with my second comment on my answer.  I doubt that anything like this can be said in infinite dimensions with the usual operator topology, but maybe we can get a result like this if we look at a different topology, or if we only look at compact (or trace-class) operators.